# Android MediaCodec issue on Alcatel OneTouch 7025D

Tags: android, android-mediacodec, alcatel-ot

I'm developing mp3 music player for Android. I use MediaCodec for decoding mp3 and AudioTrack for playing.
 My engine works fine for all phones / tablets. But on Alcatel OneTouch 7025D it works slow and wrong.
 After some test I investigated, that MediaCodec give me to large buffer: 46080 (on other devices it is 4608).
 By the way Alcatel OneTouch 7025D (Android 4.2.1) has new(2013) CPU: Quad-core 1.2 GHz Cortex-A7.
 So what could be the problem?

Comment: Query the MediaCodec decoder with `codec.getCodecInfo().getName()`.  What do you see?  I'd think the CPU would be fast enough to handle MP3 even if you were getting a software decoder.  Can you quantify what you mean by "wrong"?

Comment: @fadden :wrong" I mean it played 10 times the same note, so time of playing x10 and progress is so slowly.

Comment: @fadden I have crash on 'codec.getCodecInfo().getName()' : "AndroidRuntime" : "Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.media.MediaCodec.getCodecInfo"

Comment: Argh, `getCodecInfo()` wasn't added until API 18.  The `MediaCodecInfo` doc (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodecInfo.html) shows how to query for all codecs that handle a particular MIME type, but that doesn't necessarily tell you what you're actually using.

Comment: @fadden android:minSdkVersion="16". mime type is correct!